# Universal Hashing in Practice

Tags: data-structures, education, hash-tables, applied-theory

A family $H$ of hash functions $h: U \rightarrow \{0,\ldots,M-1\}$ is *universal* if 
$$\forall x,y \in U, x \neq y \Rightarrow \Pr_{h \in H}[h(x) = h(y)] \leq \frac{1}{M}$$
You can find more about universal hashing this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing).

The concept of universal hashing is now a standard part of undergraduate data structure courses. It would be nice to be able to motivate students about the importance of universal hashing in industrial applications. So my question is:

> Are constructions of universal family of hash functions important in practice? If the answer is yes, would you please share some interesting industrial applications that you've seen?

Comment: I expect that all implementations of generic hash structures that want to reach (amortized/expected/real) constant time cost for insert, lookup and remove (which is the only reason why we bother to hash in the first place) need a reliable way to construct "good" hashing functions. Universal hashing is a (successful) attempt at formalizing what a "good" hashing function is, and it also gives us tools to generate such functions efficiently for arbitrary keys. Since I don't have any industry experience, this is all from a theoretical point of view, but I very much expect them to be the go-to way.

Comment: @G.Bach Thanks for your comments. But I do want to hear opinions from an industrial point of view.

Comment: @Dai This is probably not the right place for get statements from industry, though.

Answer (score 4):

Universal hashing (or near-universal) is a key ingredient in defending against algorithmic complexity attacks that engineer hash table collisions from user input.

See [Scott A. Crosby and Dan S. Wallach's "Denial of Service via Algorithmic Complexity Attacks"](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/sec03/tech/full_papers/crosby/crosby.pdf).

Comment: That is very useful. I went through a similar paper as the link was broken. Will have a look at this one as well. Thanks